# Tensorflow / Keras Tutorial Save / Load Model not work

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am unable to save a simple keras Sequential model as per the tutorial using Tensorflow 1.11.0. I am able to convert the model configuration to a json string and I am able to save the weights, but not the model in its entirety.

The error comes from the first line of code in `Model.save` which checks that `self._is_graph_network` is `True`. I feel like there is something basic that I am missing, but I cannot figure it out. I believe my code is analogous to the tutorial code found here: [Keras Save and Restore](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_restore_models) in the Save Entire Model section.

```
Python 3.6.6 (default, Jun 28 2018, 05:43:53)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> import tensorflow.keras as tk
>>> mnist = tk.datasets.mnist
>>> (xtrain, ytrain), (xtest, ytest) = mnist.load_data()
>>> xtrain, xtest = xtrain/255.0, xtest/255.0
>>> model = tk.models.Sequential([tk.layers.Flatten(), tk.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu), \
tk.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)])
>>> model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
>>> model.fit(xtrain, ytrain, epochs=5)
Epoch 1/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 2s 39us/step - loss: 0.3086 - acc: 0.9126
...
Epoch 5/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 2s 37us/step - loss: 0.0715 - acc: 0.9787
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History object at 0x129819470>
>>> model.evaluate(xtest, ytest)
10000/10000 [==============================] - 0s 17us/step
[0.09259423367818817, 0.9711]
>>> model.save('m0x.h5')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mmelton/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/n\
etwork.py", line 1358, in save
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
>>> model._is_graph_network
False
>>> model.save_weights('w0.h5', save_format='h5')
>>>

>>> tf.__version__
'1.11.0'
>>> tk.__version__
'2.1.6-tf'
>>>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
model = tk.models.Sequential([
    tk.layers.Flatten(), 
    tk.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu), 
    tk.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
```

Your network has no inputs -  `Flatten(input_shape=(784,))`. Also, having `Flatten()` as your first layer is a little funny but go for it if you want.

Comment: That model creation statement is taken directly from the code in first [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/) and I can use it to fit and evaluate successfully. Adding the parameter `input_shape(28,28,)` to the `Flatten` call does indeed produce a model I can save and load. What is going on there? Specifying the input shape seems to trigger a non-obvious change.

Comment: @RandomBits Oh that's interesting that the tutorial is setup like that. My guess on what's  happening is the model is compiled without a specified input shape. This isn't an issue as you're flattening the inputs and the input dimensions are adjusted based on the input shape when training. However, when you try to save the model, it has no way to infer the input dimensions and cannot save the graph correctly.